# Rails - Couldn't find Student with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting the error above when I try to create a a 'mark' for a 'student'. I can't figure out how to pass the :student_id when I create a new mark.

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


resources :students do
resources :marks
end

resources :marks

root 'students#index'
```

Marks Controller

```
class MarksController < ApplicationController
def create
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
    @mark = @student.marks.create(params[:input1, :input2, :input3, :weight1, :weight2, :weight3, :mark1, :mark2, :mark3, :final_mark].permit(:input1, :input2, :input3, :weight1, :weight2, :weight3, :mark1, :mark2, :mark3, :final_mark))
    @mark.save

    if @mark.save
        redirect_to student_path(@student)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def new
    @mark = Mark.new
end

private 
  def set_mark
    @mark = Mark.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Students Show View

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

    <p>
     <strong>Student Number</strong>
    <%= @student.StudentNumber %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Project Title</strong>
  <%= @student.ProjectTitle %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Project PDF</strong>
  <%= @student.ProjectTitle %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Reader 1</strong>
  <%= @student.Reader1 %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Reader 2</strong>
  <%= @student.Reader2 %>
</p>

<h3> <%= link_to 'Add Mark', new_student_mark_path(@student), class:"btn btn-warning"%> </h3>

<p>
  <strong>Reader 3</strong>
  <%= @student.Reader3 %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_student_path(@student) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', students_path %>
```

Marks Form

```
<%= form_for @mark, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <% if @mark.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@mark.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this grading from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @mark.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Introduction' %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :input1 %>
    <%= f.number_field :weight1 %>
    <%= f.number_field :mark1 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Main' %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :input2 %>
    <%= f.number_field :weight2 %>
    <%= f.number_field :mark2 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Conclusion' %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :input3 %>
    <%= f.number_field :weight3 %>
    <%= f.number_field :mark3 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit class:"btn-xs btn-success"%>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Mark model

```
class Mark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
end
```

Student Model

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :marks 

has_attached_file :document
validates_attachment :document, :content_type => { :content_type => %w(application/pdf) }
end
```

It's probably something really stupid but if anyone could explain the problem I'd be really grateful.

Thanks

Comment: How you are hitting the create action?

Comment: <%= link_to 'Add Mark', new_student_mark_path(@student)%>

Comment: And in which view page this piece of code lies? Post that view code.

Comment: It's in the show page for the like of details of the student.

Comment: Please post it in the question.

Comment: Ok. Please post the code for the form for adding the mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suggest you using hidden fields for this purpose.
You should pass student together with mark into form_for helper and rails will generate proper url for you which will look like: /students/:student_id/marks
In this case it will be possible to extract student_id from params in your action later.

`form_for [@student, @mark], html: {multipart: true} do |f|`

More information about nested resources:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671632&seqNum=7

https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/3074080

UPDATE:

Forgot to mention that in order to make this work you need to pass student instance into your template at new action:

```
def new
  @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  @mark = @student.marks.build
end
```

Comment: Thanks, they helped a lot. I really appreciate it. On to the next problem now :)

Comment: Great! You are welcome. Nice to hear that you finally managed the problem.